# Wordpress Add a function after content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following code

```js
function source2(){
 ?> <p>hello world</p> <?php
}

//add beore after content
function wpdev_before_after($content) {
$beforecontent = 'This goes before the content. Isn’t that awesome!';
$aftercontent = source2();
$fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');
```

"Hello World" suppose appear after content.
However, it shows before the content instead, even before the $beforecontent.
If I insert plain text rather than calling a function, it works fine.
How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified version of the output to be displayed as per your requirement. You Need to return the string inorder to concatenate it. Unless the string is returned it will not be displayed.

> **OUTPUT:**  First Text/ Center Text /Last Text to be displayed

```
<?php
     function source2(){     
     $string = 'Last Text to be displayed';
     return $string;
     }
     //add beore after content
     function wpdev_before_after($content) {
     ob_start();    
     $beforecontent = 'First Text';
     $aftercontent = source2();
     $fullcontent = $beforecontent.$content.$aftercontent;
     return $fullcontent;
     }
     add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');
     $word="/ Center Text /";
     echo wpdev_before_after($word);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. and what if it is not a string, like.. it is a set of function

Comment: The thing is that you have to return the output from that function . Your should not print it over there or use echo inside it. Save it in a variable and use return it works even for a function.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so you need to start the output buffer and clear the output and print it again. Have a try at this .

```
function source2(){
    ?> <p>hello world</p> <?php
}

//add beore after content
function wpdev_before_after($content) {
ob_start();
$beforecontent = 'This goes before the content. Isn’t that awesome!';
$aftercontent = source2();    
$fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
$fullcontent = ob_get_clean(); 
return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but after use your code the whole content is gone except "Hellow World"

Comment: You need output like this itseems **$beforecontent** and follwed by **$content** after that **$aftercontent**. Am i right bro.

Comment: bro have a try by removing the **$fullcontent = ob_get_clean();** line from your function and tell me whether it triggers you out or not the expected output.

Comment: I removed "$fullcontent = ob_get_clean();"  and still fail. "Hello World"  appear before the content

Comment: Added another answer refer to that bro.